# Full page border | CSS

Tags: html, css, border

Isn't there a CSS way of having the page to get a border around the page, even if the content was not big enough for the page to scroll and there's still a border around the page. I think I remember I saw one CSS method before was like **something > something**, I don't know, do you know? lol

If you know, many thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to check out the following:

- [CSS Trick: Creating a Body-Border](http://css-tricks.com/body-border/) ([Live Example](http://css-tricks.com/examples/BodyBorder/))

It works in all modern browsers, except in IE6, where you can fail gracefully with a conditional stylesheet.